# Disable lowercase in Solr while indexing

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have a field in SOLR for which I need to disable `lowercasefilter`.

I explicitly created a new field type and assigned that fieldtype to a field and ensure that field should not have `lowercasefilter`.

```
<field name="link" type="strings_custom" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />    
<fieldType name="strings_custom" class="solr.TextField" />
```

Still it lowercases my field value. For example it makes `Sections` to `section`.

Comment: Is the lowercase version returned verbatim as the field value?

Comment: Reloaded, reindexed and committed?